# Silverlight - Dynamically creating controls without any postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, dynamic

Can I dynamically create controls in Silverlight without a postback to the server (even an asynchronous one). Does silverlight drag-n-drop requires postback?

I'm asking this because I've an asp.net application where I dynamically create/delete lots of controls. So after the postback I'm getting error with view state stating that the control tree doesn't match the view state tree.

Can I avoid such problems in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vast majority of what goes on in Silverlight involves no postback.  In fact, I'd say Silverlight represents a completely different mindset.  Whenever there IS a postback from Silverlight, it will almost always be asynchronous, and there is no "view state" that the server needs to worry about.  In my opinion, it makes ASP.NET look like a joke when it comes to writing web applications.

Answer (score 2):

everything done in a silverlight control/application happen on the client. web service calls if any happen asynchronously. thats on of the advantages of using silverlight

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add controls dynamically to pages, without a round-trip to the server.

Drag-drop is also executed client-side.

Think of Silverlight as more like a desktop app, that talks to the server only to get/save data.

Adding controls dynamically in Silverlight is as simple as *newing* the appropriate control class and inserting it in the render tree (e.g. by adding it to a parent control).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: http://asd.murven.com/blog/post/2009/10/16/Silverlight-Adding-controls-dynamically.aspx.

However, I would not suggest switching to Silverlight just to kill this bug. Only if you have a real need for a client-like application instead of a real web application. ASP.NET is suitable for dynamically creating controls as well. Please remember to initialize the control on the server during each postback. If this doesn't help, I would suggest you to submit a description of your problem with some code to help us solve it with you.

Br. Morten